# In Bash, how to branch on various conditions on a single-character variable?

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

Consider this Python code:

```
var = '1'
if var in '123':
    print('in 123')
elif var == 'x':
    print('is x')
elif var == 'y':
    print('is y')
```

How would one write this cleanly in Bash?

Comment: Another [case](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash’s, and indeed POSIX’s, equivalent would be [`case`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_05).

Your Python example would then translate to:

```
var='1'
case "${var}"
in
  [123])
    printf 'in 123\n'
    ;;
  x)
    printf 'is x\n'
    ;;
  y)
    printf 'is y\n'
    ;;
esac
```

You can use [POSIX pattern matching](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13) (a.k.a. globs) in the patterns, e.g. `*foo*) printf 'contains foo\n'`.

And a default ’case’ (the `default` in other languages’ `switch` constructs) would be `*)`.

Comment: That's not quite correct; `case ... in 123)` will match the string "123", not any single character in it. To match any of the single characters "1", "2", or "3", use the pattern `[123]`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Ah, I totally missed the `in` in the original code. I’ll edit.